# Complex movement within animation

Tags: apache-flex, flash, animation

I've this application, where two children are playing catch.  One throws and the other catches.  While I can show a ball object moving between two stationary objects, how do I show the objects "releasing" and "catching" the ball, in a way that is close to lifelike?

EDIT:
The movement of the hands in this game: http://www.acreativedesktop.com/animation-game-slaphands.html is what I would like to replicate.  Any tips on how to do that?

Comment: The movement in the hands is just recorded video. Place a camera somewhere steady(like a tripod). Recording a top view might be a bit tricky, but if you're actors play the game at 90 degrees towards the camera, and you don't record the whole arms(including the twist), you should be fine. There is not much related to animation with this approach

Answer (score 3):

As it's already been stated, you need animation to get it right. I suggest looking over [Preston Blair's Cartoon Animation](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Cartoon-Animation-Collectors-Preston-Blair/dp/1560100842) Book or [The Animator's Survival Kit](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Animators-Survival-Kit-Principles-Stop-motion/dp/0571202284). You won't need to read the whole thing, just reference the chapters on anticipation and accents.

For [example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAt_WPgJEaU), when one throws, the action doesn't just happen, one first prepares, anticipating the throw, building up energy. In animation you prepare the viewer for the next action, thus creating a seamless link between actions. Once the ball is thrown...there is action and re-action, so the player will return to his casual pose.

The actionscript part should be pretty simple. You should get away with 3 vectors:
1 for setting the balls movement 
1 for gravity
1 for friction/wind...etc.
Based on your parameters, you launch the ball, then use the distance between the ball and the catcher to figure out when you can you play the catcher's animation(s)

Answer (score 0):

skeletal animation is a good technique

also reverse kinematics

or even motion-capture

Comment: For a simpler implementation, just animate a few keyframes of movement. A moderately skilled artist will be able to create these for you; the brain will fill in a lot of suggested motion quite easily. The more "cartoon-like" your artwork, the better this simpler approach will work. If you need realism, then the approaches above will be better.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is essentially possible in flash... it does however sound pretty complex.  My advice would be to create static animations for the throw action and the catch action, then have these actions play when certain conditions are met (i.e. the ball gets close to one of the people).  Trying to get a lifelike throw and catch will be pretty tough. I would think even a lot of console games wouldn't attempt to do this dynamically (i do expect this is in the process or is changing in current gen games)